# ajax array data undefined

Tags: php, ajax

I have this ajax function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

setInterval(function() {

    $.ajax({
      url: 'php.php',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){
       if( data != "0" ) {
        alert(data.a);
       }
      },
    });

 }, 5000);

});
```

and a PHP to return:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

...some function

if($num>0){
    echo json_encode(array("a" => "valueA", "b" => "valueB"));
}
else{
    echo json_encode(0);
}

?>
```

when I have the alert message, it shows me "UNDEFINED" instead of "valueA".
Is something wrong with my array or ajax?

Comment: check by `console.log(data); ` what is returning by php

Comment: You know you're not posting any data, right ?

Comment: {"a":"valueA","b":"valueB"}

Comment: oh, yeah, I dont have anything to post. just want a php return value. can i remove the post part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `dataType: 'json'` to your `$.ajax` call:

```
 $.ajax({
  url: 'php.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: ...
```

`dataType` allows you to define type of data returned from server. By default, there's `intelligent quess` and maybe that's not enough.